# Can you use parents/constrains and animation nodes in the same animation?

Tags: animation-nodes

I'm new to Animation Nodes and I encounter this problem:

With three simple objects: a empty, a cube and a sphere, I have reproduced the situation I would like to implement in my project.
The cube is parented to an empty <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>), and both are free to move only on the X axis. The sphere moves through the node of the Animation Node by cube movements.

If I move the cube directly (dragging it with the mouse or changing the X coordinate in the Location fields), the Animation Node transmits its position to the sphere, but if I move the empty, the cube follows it but the sphere stays because the coordinates of the Pivot points of the cube (moved by the empty) do not change!

How do I fix this problem? Is there a way to connect the cube pivot point to the empty instead of its geometry?

Thank you and excuse the bad english: translated with google.

[Blend file](https://my.pcloud.com/publink/show?code=XZzNuGZ2lyyAEFRKYJDDzdJ8Rq1Mz8h55Yy)

Comment: there is no reason to use the <kbd>Ctlr</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> method when you can simply use animation nodes to constrain the cube to the empty (if you only want the x axis, check the x axis on the object transform output). Tell me if you would like to have an explanation in detail or if this fixed your problem... Also if for any reason you need to use the ctrl+P method, maybe you should actually use it for the cube and for the sphere (without the animation nodes)

Comment: Hi Pascal, thanks for the answer, download text (too long to be posted here) that will describe you my problems. In the text you'll find links to a rendering of my project, a Blend file, and a couple of gif animations.

Thank you.

This is the link:
https://my.pcloud.com/publink/show?code=XZcwMGZ5DiXSmKBGSfYrVwq6XRU7YStnis7

Comment: Hi, a few days ago I showed what you send me but i noticed the gif didn't animate, so i had static images. I didn't really understand what you wanted to do, and now the pcloud link is deleted, could you activate it again please?

Comment: Hi Pascal, I uploaded everything for you again on my DropBox.
This is the link:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/fl14insqea77isu/740.zip?dl=0

Thank you.

Comment: I've taken a quick look into your blend file, but didn't take time to look deeper and try to fix the problem yet. I can tell you one thing though: I think they are conflicts between animation nodes and the lock_location features. Indeed if you lock an axe with the lock_location feature, an seems to competely ignore it (maybe also the constrains). If you want to dive deeper in the animation nodes you could try and redo you work using exclusively the addon. I think the best thing to do now is to try finding a solution without the AN, because your setup seems to be pretty advanced

Comment: Sorry if I didn't really answer the question, I'm not an expert in constrains, so I think I will not find a solution implementing both an and constrains

Comment: First, the Track To constaint on BiellaCassetto was disabled, you need to click on the eye button to enable, even with which you cannot get what you want. Second, There is no light green object called "Inversion_Slitta". The light green object is called Circle.018 and tracks to Empty.004 instead of 21. Last, you are sadly right, AN conflicts with other animation you made out of AN. So Irecommended you reconsidering not using AN here. Rigging system can be a nice way here.

Comment: Hi Leon,Right, the constrain of BiellaCassetto had disabled it because it produced incorrect rotations.
The Inversion_Slitta object had become Circle.018 because after several changes I had to reimport it from the original model and point to Empty.004 and not 21 because with all the tests and modifications I had made I made mistakes and the two Empty (4 and 21) Were coincidental.
I see that you also confirm that can not mix Animation Nodes and Constrains, and I'm still unable to create this complex animation.

Thanks anyway.